# In Qt 5.1 how does the "setFlowControl" inside the QSerialPort library do?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am trying to understand and mantain an old application to represent data that a serial device (An Arduino like board in this case) is sending into the computer's Serial Port (COM3, COM4...)
The parameters which were given in the method are:

```
serial->setBaudRate(115200);
serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
serial->setDataTerminalReady(true);
serial->setRequestToSend(false);
```

The developer who wrote this application has not commented at all this code. And the Qt documentation is not very clear on how `setFlowControl` relates to `setDataTerminalReady` and `setRequestToSend`:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html#FlowControl-enum

Does setting `setFlowControl` to `NoFlowControl` overwrite the data given by `setDataTerminalReady` or `setRequestToSend`? Or does it only affect `setRequestToSend`

PS: The application works correctly. But I won't be able to compile it until a collegue sets me up with the IDE, so I can't compile and check everything for now.

Comment: Flow control is a concept used in the communication just like most of the other parameters you set: [https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/rs-232-flow-control](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/rs-232-flow-control)